# find all solutions of $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x+y+z-3)^2=0$

Tags: number-theory

find all solutions of $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x+y+z-3)^2=0$

I tried to expand this but its yielding nothing and becoming clumsy.How to do this?

Comment: Question: are you looking at integer solutions, real solutions etc.?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2+(x+y+z-3)^2\geq 0$, so this expression can never be zero for real $x,y,z$.

Comment: Since $x^2+y^2+z^2+1\geq 1$ and $(x+y+z-3)^2\geq 0$ the LHS is always greater than zero, so there are no real solutions.

Comment: thanks for the solution; how did I miss that ?? @ Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation gives $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2=0$ and $(x+y+z-3)^2=0.$ Thus you have to find the intersection of the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $x+y+z=3.$ We can prove that the distance of the plane $E:x+y+z=3$ from the point $O(0,0,0)$ is $>1.$ Indeed the distance
$d(E,O)=\big{|}\frac{0+0+0-3}{\sqrt{3}}\big{|}=\sqrt{3}>1.$ So  the two surfaces do not intersect, thus the original equation does not have any solution in ${\bf R}^3.$ If the plane had the equation $E_k:x+y+z=k$ then $d(E_k,O)=|k|/\sqrt{3},$ so $E_k$ interesects the sphere if-f $|k|\leq \sqrt{3}$ as one of the previous posters noticed.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer +1

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many complex solutions. Let $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary. Then
$$
(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x+y+z-3)^2 = 0
$$
is equivalent to
$$
z^2 + z(x + y - 3) + (x^2 + xy - 3x + y^2 - 3y + 5)=0.
$$
This has exactly $2$ complex solutions for $z$. So there are infinitely many $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{C}^3$
solving your equation.

There are no real solutions, because the LHS is greater than or equal to $1$ in your equation. Note that over a field $K$ of characteristic $2$, every triple $(x,y,z)\in K^3$ is a solution.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer +1

Answer (score 1):

While $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x+y+z-3)^2=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$,  there are solutions for $(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2+(x+y+z+k)^2=0$ when k is between $-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Did you perhaps miss the square root symbol off your question? (i.e. "$3$" should be "$\sqrt{3}$") In which case the only possibility in $\mathbb{R}$ is $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Actually, this sounds quite plausible. Maybe the OP can clarify ?

Comment: an upvote ! here it is